# Using sed to retrieve and modify a single line in the file

Tags: bash, replace, sed, grep, comments

I have a bash script that needs to comment out the first non-comment line from a file and display it, like this:

```
env=$(grep -v -m 1 "#" file)
if [ "$env" != "" ]
then
    sed -i "/\<$env\>/s/^/#/" file
fi
echo $env
```

which turns this:

```
#this is an example file
this is the first line
this is the second line
```

Into This:

```
#this is an example file
#this is the first line
this is the second line
```

And echoes this `this is the first line`

I believe there is a more straight forward, canonical way of doing this, maybe by using sed only. It would be convenient for it to be a one-liner, because it is actually executed over ssh. On the other hand, execution over ssh causes problems with expanding environment variables within sed arguments, and escaping it with `\\\$env` does not work. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already suggested, you can use `sed` only:

```
sed '0,/^[^#]/ s/^[^#].*/#\0/' file.txt
```

The above sed command applies to a range from the first line in the file until the first uncommented line. In this range it replaces the start of an uncommented line with a `#`. Because the range just applies until the first uncommented line, only this one will be commented.

Comment: No problem. `sed` rules! ;)

Comment: Yes, it does, but at the first glance, it looks like Klingon

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you are using gun `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^[^#]/{s/^/#/;:S;N;bS;}' file
```

When match the first non-comment line, it will add a `#` before the line and read remain lines.
Since it will read remain lines to the PatternSpace, if this is a big file and have many line after the first  non-comment line, it will eat large memory.

The best answer it's luis_js's, I still write my answer here just provide a different way.

Since mentioned by OP, I keep my first answer here (but it's wrong)

```
sed '/^#/{n;s/^/#/;}' file
```

It will recomments the lines after commented lines and can comment the first non-commented line only when there are odd commented lines beforce the first non-commented line.

Answer (score 1):

If you find a line with #, then go to the next line.
If next line starts with #, then go to the next line, else add #

```
sed -e '/#/{:start; n; /^#/b start; s/^/#/}; '  file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There was one answer, but it got removed. I think it is worth mentioning it, for educational purposes:

```
sed -i '/^#/{n;s/^/#/}' file
```

It's the shortest piece of code for this, BUT it comments out the comments. (you get "##" in the file). So if anyone else doesn't mind this in their particular scenario, it is still useful...

Comment: It was my answer, I found it's wrong. When you file contains two commented lines first, it will comment the second comments again and do nothing to the third line. It works only when you have odd comment lines first.