# how to add word in the end of a specific line in bash script or python?

Tags: python, bash

i would like to add a simply word in a existing file on a specific line. I already try with **sed** or **awk** or **echo**, **cat** and so on, but without expect result.

I tried with several command:

```
!/bin/bash

read nome

awk "BEGIN {print "$nome"}" > file.txt
```

File example:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
```

And i want the result:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6
```

Comment: In python, read the contents of the file using `readlines()`, giving you a list containing each line of the original file. Append your word to the line of your choice, then write all lines (including the modified one) back to a file, either the original one, or a new one.

Comment: If the final line isn't newline terminated, this is easy (change `>`, which means "write to emptied file", to `>>`, meaning "append"). If it's newline terminated, it's tougher. Which is it?

Comment: What do you mean by "specific line"? is it by line number?

Comment: OP please clarify if you always mean the last line of the file or not. answers will differ. If you don't mean the last line I will vote to reopen the question

Comment: @RyanHaining: If they want to modify a single line not at the end of the file, it's still just one more duplicate of [Editing specific line in text file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4719438/364696), or for `bash` usage (where I'm pretty sure you can assume `sed` exists), [Using sed to retrieve and modify a single line in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23957082/364696), or for changing the first line of a file [change first line of a file using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31240753/364696). The question is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: yes @HellmarBecker i mean line number

Comment: @RyanHaining yes, i meant the last line, as i wrote in my sample i wrote just 2 line, it's implied

Comment: My goal it's add, (not append), a word after the last word in the file separeted by space, i wrote "in a specific line" because i don't know if all program language support this choice

Comment: @MicheleCozzolino "on a specific line" implies you would want to be able to specify a line number. Your example uses the last line, which is easier. Can you distinguish "add" from "append"? What would add do that append wouldn't?